# How can I find the IP address for my Azure Data Factory v2 (ADF)?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to know the IP Address being used by my Azure Data Factory. I need it so I can add it to the whitelist used by a cloud service.

When I need to find the IP Address for my local machine, I can go to whatismyipaddress.com.

How can I find the IP address for my Azure Data Factory (ADF)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a json file with all the IP addresses. [Azure IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519). Search for the string `"name": "DataFactory.` and the reigon that your Data Factory is located in. For example: `"name": "DataFactory.CentralUS"`

```
{
  "name": "DataFactory.CentralUS",
  "id": "DataFactory.CentralUS",
  "properties": {
    "changeNumber": 3,
    "region": "centralus",
    "regionId": 31,
    "platform": "Azure",
    "systemService": "DataFactory",
    "addressPrefixes": [
      "13.89.174.192/28",
      "20.37.154.0/23",
      "20.37.156.0/26",
      "20.40.206.224/29",
      "20.44.10.64/28",
      "52.182.141.16/28",
      "2603:1030:10:1::480/121",
      "2603:1030:10:1::500/122",
      "2603:1030:10:1::700/121",
      "2603:1030:10:1::780/122",
      "2603:1030:10:402::330/124",
      "2603:1030:10:802::210/124",
      "2603:1030:10:c02::210/124"
    ],
    "networkFeatures": [
      "API",
      "NSG",
      "UDR",
      "FW"
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So when whitelisting IP adresses, should you whitelist all the IP adresses for (for example) DataFactory.WestEurope ??

Comment: @Cytex01 yes you should whitefish all the IP addresses for your region.

Comment: How often does Microsoft rotate the IPs for ADF?